# ¿Cómo puedo parsear un JSON en un array con react native?

Tags: json, react-native

Este es mi código:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text, FlatList} from 'react-native';

class SongNameList extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            dataSource: []
        }
    }

    renderItem = ({item}) => {
        return (<View>
            <Text>
                {item.name}
            </Text>
        </View>)
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const url = 'https://api.JSON.com/api/?option=ejemplo'
        fetch(url).then((response) => response.json()).then((responseJson) => {
            this.setState({dataSource: responseJson.VXM_POP_ESPANOL_ENERGIZANTE})
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (<View>
            <FlatList
                data = {this.state.dataSource}
                renderItem = {this.renderItem}
                keyExtractor = {(item, index) => index}
                ItemSeparatorComponent = {this.renderSeparator} />
        </View>
        );

    }
}
```

Este es mi JSON:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito que igualmente salgan los datos del segundo objeto del JSON

Comment: ¿Ambos objetos tienen la misma estructura?

Comment: Si pero no eh podido encontrar una manera de como omitir esta parte this.setState({dataSource: responseJson.VXM_POP_ESPANOL_ENERGIZANTE}) en concreto **VXM_POP_ESPANOL_ENERGIZANTE** para aparezca el otro objeto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya que ambos tienen un arreglo como valor puedes crear uno solo concatenandolos y luego pasas este arreglo a tu `state`

```
componentDidMount() {
    const url = 'https://api.JSON.com/api/?option=ejemplo'
    fetch(url).then((response) => response.json()).then((responseJson) => {
        let dataSource = [];

        Object.values(responseJson).forEach(item => {
            dataSource = dataSource.concat(item);
        });

        this.setState({dataSource: dataSource})
    });
}
```

Comment: Esto no seria posible ya que no tengo conocimiento si esos nombres puedan cambiar en un futuro :(

Comment: Edite mi respuesta para no depender de los nombres de las llaves

Comment: Muchas gracias funciono de maravilla me eh quitado el sombrero <3